# Hibernate - Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: android, hibernate, openmobster

Can anyone suggest me what causing issue for this error in hibernate.I am Using a OpenMobster Cloud Server (MBaaS tool) for data sync in Android.

```
2014-09-08 10:43:15,763 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (Thread-14) SQL  Error: 0, SQLState: null
2014-09-08 10:43:15,763 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (Thread-14)  failed batch
2014-09-08 10:43:15,764 ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener]  (Thread-14) Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 at  org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java :126)
   at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
   at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
   at   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEven tListener.java:321)
   at  org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListe ner.java:64)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:996)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1141)
   at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
   at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:835)
   at  org.openmobster.core.synchronizer.server.engine.ServerSyncEngineImpl.getChangeLogEntry(Serve rSyncEngineImpl.java:576)
   at  org.openmobster.core.synchronizer.server.engine.ServerSyncEngineImpl.addChangeLogEntries(Ser verSyncEngineImpl.java:548)
   at  org.openmobster.core.synchronizer.event.SyncChannelEventListener.updateChangeLog(SyncChannel EventListener.java:126)
   at   org.openmobster.core.synchronizer.event.SyncChannelEventListener.channelUpdated(SyncChannelE ventListener.java:95)
   at  org.openmobster.core.services.CometService.broadcastChannelEvent(CometService.java:106)
   at  org.openmobster.core.services.MobileObjectMonitor.messageIncoming(MobileObjectMonitor.java:205)
   at  org.openmobster.core.common.bus.BusConsumer.sendBusListenerEvent(BusConsumer.java:184)
   at org.openmobster.core.common.bus.BusConsumer.consume(BusConsumer.java:120)
   at org.openmobster.core.common.bus.BusConsumer.run(BusConsumer.java:77)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
   Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: failed batch
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
   at  org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:774)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
  at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
  ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the "GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update" - it does’t tell you why the given statement could not be executed.

One solution is to use BatchUpdateException.getNextException to get the reason of the batch exception. However, it may happen that this just returns null, e.g. because the jdbc driver doesn’t support it.
So the alternative solution is when we don’t get any information about the reason of the batch update failure, we have to find a way to prevent hibernate from batching. This is useful when running in an isolated environment like a testcase for example.

This can be achieved by adding the following to the system properties :

```
-Dhibernate.statement_cache.size=0 
-Dhibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 
-Dhibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset=false
-Dhibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false
-Dhibernate.show_sql=true
```

Another way to achieve this is :
For changing the execution strategy hibernate provides the hibernate.jdbc.factory_class configuration property which accepts implementations of org.hibernate.jdbc.BatcherFactory.
Hibernate already provides the NonBatchingBatcherFactory, which is what we want in our case.
The appropriate hibernate configuration might look like this:

```
final Configuration config = new Configuration();
// ... more config here
config.setProperty( "hibernate.jdbc.factory_class", "org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcherFactory" );
```

The code that produced the BatchUpdateException above would now result in actual exception which can be easily traced.  it’s helpful to change the batcher strategy once for a test run to see individual sql exceptions.  But you should not change the strategy for all tests or for continuous integration while production settings are different.

Reference:

1. http://www.eishay.com/2010/04/testing-with-hibernate.html
2. http://inoio.de/blog/2012/11/16/how-to-get-rid-of-hibernate-genericjdbcexception/